# Our own class to zip file using deflate and fastest compression level

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, zip, compression

I am using [ZIpstorer](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/) class library to compress files. It has got `Deflate` and `store` compression methods.It works well and proper. I have compared (binary compare ) of zip file generated by this library and the one created by 7zip softwate and they are binary same. But after compress using deflate option I found that there is some binary changes in zip files cretaed by Zipstorer and 7zip. It is because 7zip has a compression level logic and it was set to `Fastest`.

Now I want to implement same kind of compression level- fastest with compression method- deflate. I tried to understand the code ZIpstorer and zip file format but didn't get any idea. So can anyone help to implement fastest compression level with deflate?

Comment: I suspect it's perfectly feasible for zip files with identical contents, compression methods and compression levels to be different at a binary level. Why do they need t match 7-zip's output?

Comment: @spender in case of store method it was binary same.can u pls tell me how they can be different? Also my question is to implement fastest compression level with deflate.

Comment: ["Extra" fields](http://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/KB/0610242300.aspx) can contain arbitrary data.

Comment: @spender is correct.  There is no reason to expect different implementations of deflate compressors at different or even the same compression levels to produce identical binary output.  What you should be checking is that it _decompresses_ to the identical binary _input_ to the compressor.

Answer (score 1):

So, looking at [the source](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/downloads/get/110900), I can see that `ZipStorer` instantiates a `DeflateStream` with the following [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yy62ycx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call...

```
new DeflateStream(this.ZipFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
```

You'll need to make a change to the [`ZipStorer` class](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/downloads/get/110900) (line 588 at time of writing) so that it uses [this `DeflateStream` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137322%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

It it were me, I'd prefer [`DotNetZip`](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) or even [`ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) over [`ZipStorer`](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/downloads/get/110900).

Comment: Just using CompressionLevel.Fastest instead of compression method not working gives error like "The name 'CompressionLevel' does not exist in the current context" . I think CompressionLevel is not available in .net 3.5. I am using .net 3.5. I want it to work in .net 3.5 also.

Comment: But DotNetZip have given only DLL i guess? Did they provide complete code of the library?

Comment: Really? The source is available on [this page](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/68268) or in a [subversion repository](https://dotnetzip.svn.codeplex.com/svn). Unless you want to make modifications, just install the nuget package into your project by entering the following into the package manager console: `Install-Package DotNetZip `  and you're good to go...

Comment: ok. In my case i require to zip folders , in this case i loop through sub folders and then for each file i call zip.AddFile function.if i do this way zip file will contain all file in a single folder inside zip. So how to create a folder structure inside a zip file?

Comment: It's all in [the docs](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/d4648875-d41a-783b-d5f4-638df39ee413.htm). See [this overload](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/202e1fb5-8891-888f-8e91-1340f7cd80c9.htm) of `AddFile`.

Comment: Ok. same thing is applicable to zipstorer?

Comment: @ITresearcher : It's time for you to ask a new question. I'm not your personal tech support.

Comment: ok. i have posted new question for that(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231171/zip-a-folder-having-subfolders-using-zipstorer-class)  .But from this link dotnetzip.codeplex.com/releases/view/68268 i downloaded DotNetZip-src-v1.9.1.8.zip and i didnt get source of the library.Am i missing something?