# Zip a folder having subfolders using zipstorer class

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, zip, compression, zipstorer

I am using [ZIpstorer](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/) class library to compress files. I am able to zip a file by calling `zip.AddFile` procedure. But I want to zip folders which has subfolders too. So the resulting zip file should have folder and subfolder structure inside the zip file normally. I am not able to do it. if i process each file by looping all folders and sub folders and then if call `zip.Addfile` then it will result in zip file with all the files inside it without a directory structure.

So how can i zip a folder using Zipstorer class . What changes i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (back)slashes for the `_filenameInZip` (sic) parameter to add files in a directory in the zip:

```
zip.Addfile(,,"directory/filename.txt",);
```

Or

```
zip.Addfile(,,"directory\\filename.txt",);
```

Comment: Ok. So i should have to loop through all the files in all directories and pas its relative path to Addfile. Is there any other method which will improve performance and speed?

Comment: @ITresearcher I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean to say i have to loop through all files in directory and call zip.Addfile for each file as u mentioned in answer. Is that only way of doing it?Your solution works well. Also only problem is if a sub folder has no files then it will not be added to zip. So how can i include blank folders?

Comment: @ITresearcher yes, the code of that class isn't that versatile that you can just pass it a directory to zip. Anyway, if it did support that, then that code would loop over the files too. As for your "empty folder" edit, I don't know. It's not that great a class, just use a more commonly used library that does support it.

Comment: Please don't turn this into a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). You've picked a poor solution (using a simple class instead of a full-blown library), then you'll have to live with the consequences or switch to a library instead.

Comment: Ok. So can you please advice me a better library?